# Unity вылетает каждый раз при входе в playmode после добавления assembly definitions

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-editor

Я пытался добавить рекламу с помощью пакета Unity `Ads Mediation`. При установке пакета создается новая сборка в папке `Editor` с именем `MobileDependencyResolverLP.Installer.Editor`, и, поскольку у меня были эдитор скрипты, Unity показала ошибку, что некоторые классы, которые находятся в предопределенной сборке, неизвестны: [image: Ошибка недоступности]
Поэтому я добавил новую сборку в папку `Scripts` и добавил ссылку в `MobileDependencyResolverLP.Installer.Editor` на эту сборку
[image: MobileDependencyResolverLP.Installer.Editor]
[image: Scripts]
Ошибки исчезли, но каждый раз, когда я запускаю playmode, Unity просто закрывается.

Что я сделал не так?